# CMake doesn't add /usr/include to include_directories list

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build a CMake project with a customed `arm-linux-..g++` compiler. This project is using some third-party library (`libzmq` for the manner of sake). Now the problem is that when I install `libzmq`, it puts the header file in `/usr/include`, but my compiler doesn't search for `.h` files there.

I tried the following:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(LIBZMQ REQUIRED libzmq)

// Now I have a variable ${LIBZMQ_INCLUDEDIR} populated with /usr/include - checked it

include_directories(
 ${LIBZMQ_INCLUDEDIR}
)

...
```

The problem is, that CMake won't add the `/usr/include` path to the list of `-I..` in the `flags.make`, I guess it's because CMake assumes that this path is in the search path of the compiler anyway.

How do I deal with this?

Comment: Is `arm-linux-...g++` a cross-compiler?  It probably has its own sysroot, so you really don't want `/usr/include` in your include path.

Comment: It is a cross-compiler, and it does have its own sysroot. So what is the best way to deal with this kind of scenario? Manual copying the `.h` file to the include directory of the sysroot?

Comment: You'll have a get a copy of every library you need compiled for your target architecture and installed in the sysroot.  Make sure you have a cmake toolchain file that specifies the sysroot, and everything should pretty much just work.